# ALB health check issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, tomcat, aws-alb

I have ALB and has one of target group (type IP) where i have spring boot application.Health check for this target is failing with HTTP 502
We are using tomcat image for spring boot application.

Health check configure are

```
Protocol : HTTP
Path : /Query
Port: traffic port
Healthy Threshold: 2
Unhealthy Threshold: 3
Timeout : 2
Interval :5 
Success-code : 200
```

I am using tomcat image for this spring boot application.Is the timeout given very less and that might be cause of 502 ? But it was working with same configuration earlier.

Comment: 2 seconds should be more than enough to route the traffic within AWS infrastructure unless your instance is under too much load. I would start by checking whether you can actually access that `/Query` path to which you are sending health checks.

Comment: @ Matus Dubrava My ALB  is internal so what way i can access /Query path ?

Comment: Not through ALB but directly from within the instance that is hosting your application.

Comment: @ Matus Dubrava I have to ping the private IP from Instance?

Comment: No. Ping is L3 (network layer) test. You need to test the application layer and specifically the `/Query` path. You can use `curl` to test the URL from within the instance.

Comment: @ Matus Dubrava $curl ALB-DNS/Query should be fine right ?

Comment: No, you should query the instance directly. You need to find out whether the instance is responding to ALB health checks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Spring Security? If you are, you probably need to allow the ALB to access to the path of the Health Check without being authenticated.

```
.antMatchers("/actuator/health", "/actuator/info").permitAll()
```